# data source setup jooq with spring

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, weblogic, jooq

Getting below error when using bonecp datasource with jooq and spring boot and deployed on weblogic server.

Below is my settings:

```
    bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes=1
    bonecp.idleMaxAgeInMinutes=4
    bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition=1
    bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
    bonecp.poolAvailabilityThreshold=5
    bonecp.partitionCount=1
    bonecp.acquireIncrement=1
```

And the error is:

```
for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "712" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 712707 ms", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". 
Stack trace:
        sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
        com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:82)
        com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90)
        com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553)
        com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be related to jOOQ, the error happens before jOOQ is involved... Could you provide more information about your setup, and about how you're using / configuring your connection pool in your WLS deployment?

Comment: My steup is below:   jooq + spring boot deployed in weblogic 12 server with jdk 1.8 ...This seems like the connection not available problem..... for debugging how do i check the current count of connection available in the data source pool..i have no access to check this from database side...the only way i can check is in the code

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I don't see your code... The information you've provided so far is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

This is not jOOQ or connection pooling issue, but related to weblogic.

> Also,
>   consider setting the WebLogic Server “Stuck Thread Max Time” value
>   from its default 600 seconds to a larger value such as 1200 seconds.
>   Use the WebLogic Console to change this value (base_domain >
>   Environment > Servers > Admin Server > Configuration/Tuning).

See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-3745/ghudn/index.html.